# How to cause `make` to autogenerate missing dependency file?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, ibm-midrange

I've set up a makefile for GNU make 4.0 using Paul Smith's guide [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine). Everything seems to work except if a .d file is deleted, it isn't recreated with the next `make all`.  According to the guide, if the autogenerated dependency file is listed as a dependency of the target, then `make` will recreate it if it's missing:

```
%.o : %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
        $(POSTCOMPILE)
```

Paul's explanation:

> `... $(DEPDIR)/%.d`
>
> Declare the generated dependency file as a
>   prerequisite of the target, so that if it’s missing the target will be
>   rebuilt.

This is not my experience. Deleting a `.d` file and re-issuing `make all` results in make deciding that everything is up to date.  Forcing a recompile of the .c does of course recreate the dependency file, but aren't dependency files supposed to get rebuilt whenever they are missing?

Excerpts from my makefile (this is on an IBM i so it's not using GCC, but the MAKEDEP parameter causes the creation of a dependency file):

```
POSTCCOMPILE =  mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

%.MODULE: %.C
%.MODULE: %.C $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    @system -v "crtcmod module($(OBJLIB)/$*) srcstmf('$<') MAKEDEP('$(DEPDIR)/$*.Td')"
    @$(POSTCCOMPILE)

. . .

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

. . .

-include $(wildcard $(DEPDIR)/*.d)
```

Sticking with this method of generating dependency files, what needs to be done to have `make` recreate missing `.d` files (keeping in mind the possibility that not every C file has includes)?

Answer (score 3):

Hm.  It appears that a missing pattern prerequisite does not force the pattern target to rebuild.  In other words, if make finds a pattern rule to build a prerequisite but that rule doesn't end up creating the prerequisite file, then the pattern target is not considered out of date.  That's actually surprising to me, and not expected.  I'm not sure if there's a documented justification of this or a use for it, or if it's just an oversight.  If it's a bug it's been around for quite a while.  I'd have to think about it more.

To solve your immediate problem you can change the pattern rule into an explicit rule and that will fix things.  This is because if the prerequisite is built by an explicit rule which doesn't create the prerequisite file, it's still considered updated and the target is considered out of date.

For example if you have a variable say `SRCS` which contains a list of all the source files, then if you change these lines:

```
$(DEPDIR)/%.d : ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d
```

to this instead:

```
$(SRCS:%.C=$(DEPDIR)/%.d) : ;
```

it will all work as expected.

Or you can do the same type of thing if you have a list of objects instead: just modify the substitution appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have both these lines?

```
%.MODULE: %.C
%.MODULE: %.C $(DEPDIR)/%.d
```

I believe the second line should be sufficient, and the first line may be causing `make` to find a rule for building `%.MODULE` that doesn't require `$(DEPDIR)/%.d`.

Comment: According to the linked article, the first line removes any built-in rules for that item.  Probably not necessary in my case, because GNU make likely does not have a built-in rule for a module.  Just to be safe, I took it out -- with no effect.